# движение объекта в заданную точку

Tags: unity3d, перемещение

Всем привет. Делаю простенькую игру на юнити, и у меня возникла проблема. У меня есть персонаж, которым мы управляем свайпами (свайп вправо - персонаж движется вправо, свайп влево - движется влево). На разных экранах персонаж может недолетать/перелетать нужную точку. Подскажите, как это исправить? Вот сам код:

```
public Vector2 targetPos;
public float Xincrement;

public static bool isRun = false;
public static bool isRight = false;
public float speed;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPos, speed * Time.deltaTime);

    if (isRight == true && isRun == true)
    {
        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y);
        isRun = false;
    }
    else if (isRight == false && isRun == true)
    {
        targetPos = new Vector2(transform.position.x - Xincrement, transform.position.y);
        isRun = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Расставь пустые объекты на нужные координаты, а там и в самом скрипте напиши, чтобы по свайпу, если персонаж в одной точке, то пошел в другую

Comment: Из твоего кода ВООБЩЕ ничего не понятно. Все публичное, задается непонятно как и каким образом и каким принципам? Не используя физику, почему-то используешь `FixedUpdate`. Без конца чекаешь `isRun`, задаешь `targetPos` как позицию самого себя или в право на `Xincrement` в зависимости от флага `isRight`, а возможно еще задается из-вне... У тебя вообще какое движение? По клеткам или как? Что за загадочные "нужные точки"? Откуда они берутся?